# sonatype nexus admin login failed

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have got sonatype nexus 2.9.0 - 04

It's up and running my setting file looks like this :

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<security-configuration>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
  <anonymousAccessEnabled>true</anonymousAccessEnabled>
  <anonymousUsername>anonymous</anonymousUsername>
  <anonymousPassword>{Axpt3JeRQ5EH5kGiivKV9kuHZZAW60lps3pRuMnnCgE=}</anonymousPassword>
  <realms>
    <realm>XmlAuthenticatingRealm</realm>
    <realm>XmlAuthorizingRealm</realm>
    </realms>
    <hashIterations>1024</hashIterations>
 </security-configuration>
```

But I am unable to login with admin/admin123.

I have tried anonymous/anonymous123 but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a private browser window/tab to log in, this will disable any plugins/extensions you have installed which may be interfering.

Also you could try resetting the admin password as described here:

https://sonatype.zendesk.com/entries/24893021

Note that that resetting this password won't be necessary if this is a new installation.